# jQuery hide and show in Safari mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile, hide, show

I want to hide and show an image, but it's not working in mobile safari. Only the css border of the image appears after the show() call.
(it works in all normal browsers, this bug is just in mobile Safari) The image loads properly when i comment out the hide() call. Can someone help me?

```
$(function() {
    $('.module_imgs').hide();
    $('.module_btn').click(function() {
        $('.module_imgs').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: have you got same issue using fadeOut/fadeIn

Comment: Hmm no, replacing hide with fadeOut and show with fadeIn works! (But I don't want it to fadeOut, it should be invisible when opening the page)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I made the div element empty and used appendChild to show my images. Not really the solution I wanted, but it works.